# Problem with binding event handler to a dynamically created element

Tags: jquery

I have just started learning HTML, CSS and jQuery and I am new. I searched for binding event handlers to dynamically added elements and I found out I have to use the parent of the dynamic element as the static selector and add the dynamic element after the event method ( Correct me if I am wrong). 
  `$(staticAncestors).on(eventName, dynamicChild, function() {});`  
 But I do not know why the code below does not work when I change :

1. `$("#p1")`  with  `$(this)`  
   or
2. `$(document)`  with  `$("div")`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div").click(function(){
        $(this).html('<p id="p1" style="background: red;">Paragraph one</p> <p>Paragraph two</p>').css('margin', '15px 15px 15px 15px');
    });
    $(document).on('click', '#p1', function(){
        $("#p1").css('background-color', 'blue');
    });
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div> It's a div. </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Very strange. Adding `console.log(this.id);` shows that the handler is running. But for some reason the CSS isn't changing.

Answer (score 3):

**According to Jquery Docs https://api.jquery.com/on/**

> By default, most events bubble up from the original event target to
> the document element (In your case from #p1). At each element along
> the way, jQuery calls any matching event handlers that have been
> attached. A handler can prevent the event from bubbling further up the
> document tree (and thus prevent handlers on those elements from
> running) by calling event.stopPropagation().

Here is your working code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div").click(function(){
        $(this)
        .html('<p id="p1" style="background: red;">Paragraph one</p> <p>Paragraph two</p>')
        .css('margin', '15px 15px 15px 15px');        
        
    });

    $("div").on('click', 'p', function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
        $(this).css('background-color', 'blue');
    });
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div> It's a div. </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ahh, the problem is that the other event handler is running and replacing the html again, wiping out the CSS change.

Comment: Yes, if you print following in console

console.log($(this));

you'll get Node but when you click on that node you will get a info message like this "Node cannot be found in the current page."

Comment: So you mean that the first `.click` function overrides the `.on(click)` function? If you mean that this is the problem, why using `$(document)` and `$("#p1")` works but changing any of them stops the code snippet? Even if you only change `$("#p1")` with `$(this)` it prevents the code from running.

Comment: @someone `$(document)` works because `document` is the parent of `div`. When you use `div` it is the same element that has already click listener attached.